# OpenNMS Name OID to Numeric OID translation in Java

Tags: java

I am using OpenNMS for the first time, and I simply want to take a fully resolved OID like `sysContact.0` and get its dot numeric representation and vice versa.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My question is which class files do I use in OpenNS that will allow me to resolve SNMP OIN names and vice versa